# Axes fonts with text.usetex 'true' does not use set font

Tags: python, matplotlib

I set the font style in the matplotlibrc param file to Helvetica (sans serif) and I set text.usetex to 'True' but the axes fonts use serif fonts. How do I get the axes fonts to use sans serif?

Comment: Please show us your code you have so far ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing your .matplolibrc won't be enough. For example in OS X Helvetica is installed per default but stored as a `.dfont` file which is inaccessible to Matplotlib. If this is the case you need to convert it to `.ttf` and place it in the right folder so that matplotlib can see it. Please see [here](http://blog.olgabotvinnik.com/blog/2012/11/15/2012-11-15-how-to-set-helvetica-as-the-default-sans-serif-font-in/) for more details.

Something like this will help you troubleshoot the issue:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

path = '/home/username/Helvetica.ttf'
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Test text', fontproperties=prop, size=40)
```

To see all fonts available to you:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
print matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None)
```

Comment: The x and y-ticks font does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and it was resolved by setting an additional rcparam for the font itself. I.e. using this code gives me the problem you describe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {
'text.usetex': True,
'font.family': 'sans'
}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

Modifying by setting the 'font.sans' option resolved the problem for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {
'text.usetex': True,
'font.family': 'sans',
'font.sans': 'cm'
}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```